# My male cat (6 months old) uses too much his nail on us

Tags: cats

So my kitten is REALLY needy and wants us (me and my wife) to play with him ALL the time, like for hours. We make him jump and run in order to make him tired, but still he has a lot of energy to spare. The problem is that when we don't want to play with him anymore (because we are tired), he starts to jump on our legs. I don't know what to do in order to make him know that it is not ok to jump on our legs using his nails (I think that he uses it without knowing).

Also, there is another scenario where he uses his nail on us. Whenever we are sit he wants to sit on our lap and wants some massage. The problem is that after some time (like 20 min or so) when we need to get up to do something, he does not allow us to do that. When we try to take him off our lap he tries to bite us (like a warning bite) and then he digs his nail on us to not allow us to take him off. I don't know what to do in order to take him off on those scenarios or to say that it is not ok to use his nail on us.

Comment: Related: https://pets.stackexchange.com/questions/6735/at-what-age-can-you-start-clipping-a-cats-nails https://pets.stackexchange.com/questions/6490/can-a-grown-cat-be-taught-to-play-without-using-claws https://pets.stackexchange.com/questions/220/how-can-i-prevent-my-cat-from-extending-his-claws-when-being-petted